# How can I reload a script in infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll, masonry

Firstly, I don't know if I'm using the rights words to describe this situation. Secondly, I don't know how to code js so I will try to describe this thing as best as I can. I'm basically making a tumblr theme with masonry and infinite scroll. I'm using the latest version of both masonry and infinite scroll. Both of them work perfectly as well. The thing is, all the posts appended through infinite scroll don't seem like the initial posts. I use these codes to unnest blockquotes and tweak the photosets:

```js
// Unnest
$('.post').unnest({
    yourCaption: ".caption, .text_body", 
    wrapName: ".tumblr_parent", 
    newCaptionUsername: true, 
    originalPostCaptionUsername: false, 
    tumblrAvatars: true, 
    tumblrAvatarClass: ".tumblr_avatar", 
    usernameColon: false 
});
// For legacy photosets
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.photo-slideshow').pxuPhotoset({
        lightbox: true,
        rounded: false,
        gutter: '3px',
        photoset: '.photo-slideshow',
        photoWrap: '.photo-data',
        photo: '.pxu-photo'
    });
});
// For NPF photosets
var npfOptions = {
    includeCommonPhotosets: false,
    photosetMargins:"3"
}
npfPhotosets(".post", npfOptions);
```

The posts appended through infinite scroll don't seem to be affected by these codes at all. Here's the code for masonry and infinite scroll that I use:

```js
var $grid = $('#posts').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.post',
    columnWidth: 1
});
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry();
});  

// get Masonry instance
let msnry = $grid.data('masonry');

// init Infinite Scroll
$grid.infiniteScroll({
  // Infinite Scroll options...
  append: '.post',
  path: '.next_page',
  outlayer: msnry
});
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   Nothing (obviously) wrong with your question, just advising that the [tour] is there to be read.

Comment: When you run code such as `$("selector")` it will only select the elements that exist at the time the code runs.  So your elements added later aren't affected.   It's like saying "rip up these pieces of paper... rip... here's another piece of paper, why isn't it ripped? - because you didn't have it when you ripped the first lot".    The answer is to re-run the code against the newly added elements after they have been added - infiniteScroll should have a callback or event to hook into.  See https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your initial functions should be called after every time new stuff is added to the page. You can do so by using the event provided by infinite-scroll, as follows:

```
var infiniteGrid = $grid.infiniteScroll({
    // Infinite Scroll options...
    append: '.post',
    path: '.next_page',
    outlayer: msnry
});
infiniteGrid.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path, items ) {
    // do your thing with the new items here
});
```